# Keras model gives wrong predictions of only 1 class

Tags: deep-learning, keras

#### Background

I used Python and Keras to implement the model of **[1]**.

The model's structure is described in Fig.3 of this paper:

- **[1]** Zheng, Y.: Time Series Classification Using Multi-Channels Deep Convolutional Neural Networks, 2014

#### Problem

The trained model gives predictions of only 1 class out of 4 classes. For example, [3,3,3,...,3] (= all 3's)

#### My code at [*Github*](https://github.com/krittameth-teacha/mc-dcnn)

- Run *main_q02.py*
- The model is defined in *mcdcnn_3.py*
- Utility functions are defined in *utils.py* and *PAMAP2Utils.py*

#### Dataset [*Download*](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00231/)

The code requires only two files:

- PAMAP2_Dataset/Protocol/subject101.dat
- PAMAP2_Dataset/Protocol/subject102.dat

**About the dataset**

1. The dataset classes are **NOT** balanced.

   - class:   0, 1, 2, 3
   - number of samples (%):   28.76%, 36.18%, 18.42%, 16.64%
   - Note: computed over all 7 subjects
2. Does one dominate? Classes 0 and 1 dominate around 65% of all samples.

   - class 0: 28.76%
   - class 1: 36.18%

#### Additional details

**Operating system:**   Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

**Version of python packages:**

- Theano (0.8.2)
- Keras (1.1.0)
- numpy (1.13.0)
- pandas (0.20.2)

#### Details of the model (from the paper):

- "separate multivariate time series into univariate ones and perform feature learning on each univariate series individually." **[1]**
- "adopt sigmoid function in all activation layers" **[1]**
- "utilize average pooling without overlapping" **[1]**
- use stochastic gradient descent (SGD) for learning
- parameters: momentum = 0.9, decay = 0.0005, learning rate = 0.01

Comment: This model is being trained for just one epoch, how do you expect that to make sense?

Comment: Well the problem is training, there are lots of details missing in your questions, like, are the dataset classes balanced? Does one dominate? When you train, does the loss converge? Training a neural network model is not only a mater of programming, you need to also experiment with the parameters such as learning rate, number of epochs and make learning converge.

Comment: Thanks for your advice :)